# No public members in abstract class

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class, class-design

I'm constructing some code that interacts with a HTTP web service.  To interact with it, you invoke "commands" on it, either with HTTP GET requests or with HTTP POST.

I want to create a base class (eg, ServiceCommand) that encapsulates and hides an HttpWebRequest object, but I'm not convinced I want it to offer any functionality publicly, only to subclasses.

Subclasses could be (for example) SearchCommand, or FetchCommand, and these would use the functionality offered by the protected methods in the base class.

Basically, my question is: Is it considered bad design to create classes that have only protected members, and no public ones.

Comment: I'd say it's better to use them and stick to OOP than not to use them.

Comment: How would you ever invoke the functionality of the implementations if you don't have any public members? The constructor?

Comment: I don't know of any reason not to, but it just seems strange seeing a class with no public members.  I can't find any examples of this in the .NET framework, which makes me question whether it is a good idea.

Comment: There is no public functionality to invoke.  The functionality is common functionality to all subclasses however, which is why it would have several protected members.

Comment: This does not sound as `is-a` relationship, but rather `has a` or `uses`. Have you considered moving your wrapper to a separate class and calling it from `XCommand`, which looks more like your case? You can still have common interface for all command classes if you want to.

Comment: Basically it is not good design to have a base class if the derived classes don't have anything in common. Instead you could create a common interface for SearchCommand or FetchCommand and factory class that creates instance for one of them. Suggestion: The interface could contain the method ExecuteCommand(String param).

Comment: I had considered it, but decided against.  This discussion is making me question it again though.

Comment: @dark_perfect, what was the reasoning for that decision?

Comment: I think you are right, Andrei.  Just because the classes share similar names, I am trying to force it into an is-a relationship, whereas it should be a has-a relationship.  I think I incorrectly think that they SHARE common functionality, whereas in truth, they USE common functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General questions I ask myself with design:

- What is it that this class **IS**. Remember that object oriented design is about objects. If you are creating a new object you need to be able to think about it as an individual entity (at least abstractly). If you are just providing functionality you might be better off creating an interface or extension methods.
- Does this functionality already exist? No need to create a class to wrap a class that worked well.
- Finally with private versus public - if you think that subclasses will need to access base class values create a protected member variable. This variable will work whether or not you have a public property in the base class. Once you do this - if you think the value would be useful externally, you can add a get/set in the base class. This ends up looking like:

  ```
  public abstract class BaseClass {
      protected object _member;
      public object MemberGet { return _member; }
  }

  public class InheritClass : BaseClass {
      // now the base class can "decide" to set the member or implement its own set rules
      public static void RoutineThatSetsMember(object value) { _member = value; }
  }
  ```

I'm not sure if these are rules everyone uses but maybe it will help with general design (Or at least keep the conversation moving forward)!

Answer (score 2):

This is a question regard to the difference between "Is A" and "Has A".

Regards to "Is A", if class B inherits from interface A or class A, it is means B is one type of A, B should has the same behavior as  A has, while these behaviors are defined by public member functions.

As "Has A", Class B just want to use the implementation of Class A, so B will hold the reference to A, instead of inheriting from A.

so for your case, it is a "Has A" relationship.